# Ипорт библиотеки python3 "по спортивному"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как импортировать библиотеку python3 без слова импорт. Вроде это как то делается через два нижних подчеркивания. Напомните плз.

Answer (score 3):

```
module = __import__(script_name)
```

Возможно понадобится добавить путь для поиска скрипта `sys.path.append(script_path)`

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к `__import__`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html

```
import importlib
itertools = importlib.import_module('itertools')
```